# Holomorphic function expressed in terms of an integral

Tags: complex-analysis

> Question: Let $\gamma \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ be continuous and piecewise differentiable function and let $f$ be continuous complex-valued fucntion on $\gamma([a,b])$. Suppose $f(z) \neq \xi$ for all $z \in \gamma([a,b])$ and $\xi \in \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is a domain in $\mathbb{C}$. Show that the function
> $$g(\xi) = \int_\gamma \frac{1}{f(z) - \xi}\, dz$$
> is analytic function on $\Omega$.

My attempt: Using Morera's theorem, it suffices to show that $g$ is continuous in $\Omega$ and $\int_\Delta g(\xi) \, d \xi =0$ for any triangle contained in $\Omega$. Let $\xi_0 \in \Omega$ and $(\xi_n) \subset \Omega$ be converging to $\xi_0$, we have
$$|g(\xi_n) - g(\xi_0)| \leq \int_a^b |\gamma'(t)| \frac{|\xi_0 - \xi_n|}{|f(\gamma(t)) - \xi_n| |f(\gamma(t)) - \xi_0|}\, d \xi$$
Is there any way I can uniformly bound the set $\{|f(\gamma(t)) - \xi| \colon t \in [a,b], \xi = \xi_0, \xi_1, \dots\}$ from below? As I am able to show that for any $n = 0,1,2\dots$,
$$\inf\{|f(\gamma(t) - \xi_n| \colon t \in [a,b]\} >0$$

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491182/42969

Comment: There is a neighborhood of $\xi_0$ which misses $f\circ\gamma$ by some non-zero distance, and only a finite number of the $\xi_n$ lie outside that neighborhood.